# How to set the props after a button is clicked in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a waiting room feature in my system, if the user has clicked the join room then he/she will need to wait until the moderator will accept the request.

I have two function components, App.js where I set the props and Room.js where I need to call the props. If anyone knows this, kindly help.

So far I have this logic, how can I successfully call the props by clicking the button?

```
App.js

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Props</h1>
      <Room name="joined" />
      <input type="button" to />
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component={Link} to={`/${data}`}>Join Room</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Room.js

```
function Room(props){

    if(props.name == "joined"){
        console.log("Accept")
    } else {
        console.log("Wait")
    }

    return(
                <div>Room</div>
    )
}

export default Room;
```

Comment: What do you mean by calling the props?

Comment: @SinanYaman - by setting it to the Room component. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass props as such:

```
<Room {...props} />
```

This will pass all the fields inside the `props` object. Example:
Let's say props = `{name: "name", value:"value"}`. By passing props like `<Room {...props} />` you can access the props inside `Room` component like:

```
function Room({name, value}) {}
```

#### Another way

You can also pass props explicitly:

```
<Room name={props.name} roomValue={props.value} />
```

#### Conditional rendering

If you need to render the `Room` component only after the button click, you can use a conditional rendering:

```
import {useState} from 'react'

const [renderRooms, setRenderRooms] = useState(false)

const handleBtnClick = e => setRenderRooms(true)

return(
  <div>
    ...
    {renderRooms && <Rooms {...props} />}
  </div>
)
```

#### Passing state to child

You can change parent component's state by passing the state variable and the setter to the child:

```
const [joined, setJoined] = useState(false)

const handleJoin = () => setJoined(true)

return (
  ...
  <Rooms joined={joined} />
  <Button onClick={handleJoin} variant="contained" color="primary" component={Link} to={`/${data}`}>Join Room</Button>
)
```

I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-paper-zz4f3?file=/src/App.js). It is not immediately clear to me what the intent is, but I created a use case where you pass props to the child, and it changes with  a button click. I think you can pick it up from here.

Comment: is there a way that the button will trigger that prop? like for example after I clicked the Button then the console log will show if it is true or false.

Comment: Updated the answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: the 3rd option "Passing state to child" it looked like it worked but I have changed few codes of it like the `Room joind={joined}` I have changed it to `<Room name="joined" />` and it worked but not sure if I am correct or it is not?

Comment: It is totally preference, I just used `joined` as an example. However, `name="joined"` will constantly pass `joined` as prop value. So you can do, `name={joined ? "joined" : "not joined"}` or something.

Comment: Alright, finally how can I trigger the console log only after clicking the button? because right now even if it was not clicked, the console log was showing. It is correct though but is there a way to fix this ? thank you

Comment: Since you are not conditionally rendering `Rooms` and not chaning the props `name`, Room will always get the prop `name` as joined. You can try changing a state variable called `joined` as in my answer and pass the name prop conditionally like I mentioned in the above comment

Comment: ok I replaced it with `name={joined ? "joined" : "not joined"}` but instead of being removed it has constant value of "Wait" - Am I missing something with the Room.js ? should I edit something or change something there?

Comment: I will create a codesandbox and update the answer once done.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check it. Good luck! Also kindly accept this as the answer if it works out :)

Comment: I am still getting the "Wait" by default in console log haha, is there anyway to fix this problem?

Comment: If you can create a `codesandbox` with the same issue, I will take a look

Comment: ok here you go [Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-snow-9y9zw?file=/Room.js)

Comment: kindly inspect it so you can see the console, the wait must be removed, thank you if there is a way?

Comment: When the component first mounts, props.name is `not joined` since joined is `false`. So, you see the "Wait".  You can default `joined` to true by: `const [joined, setJoined] = useState(true);` and you won't see "Wait"

Comment: I am just figuring it out because I want the console log to be empty for the loading of the page, I just want to show the "Accept" or "Wait" once the button was clicked.

Comment: don't you mind if you also answer this? I am near to my goal. Thank you [Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68803520/how-to-pass-value-to-other-function-component-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

In your App.js

```
function App(){
  const buttonClick = () => {
      //do whaterver yout want
  }
 return (
     <div>
         <Room buttonClick={buttonClick} name="joined"/>
     </div>
 )
}
```

and in Room.js

```
function Room(props){
   return( 
    <button onClick={() => props.buttonClick()}/>
   )
}
```

Comment: is there a way that the trigger will be first initialize at the App.js?

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you are asking for