# How to pass value to other function component in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to pass the value to other page or function component, is there a way to do it?
Here's what I have done. I am already passing a value but only to the "Home" component. I would like to pass the value from the "Room" component but every time I navigate to its link. I cannot see the value, however, I can only see the value from the "Home" component.

Tried it by inspecting the browser -> console, and only Home component got the correct value, Room component does not have but it should have it too

`localhost:3000/home` -> consoles are working fine here it has "Wait" and "Accept" for successful response

`localhost:3000/room` -> consoles are not working here, only "Wait"

What I would like to have is when I clicked the button on the "Home" component, the success of console must also be shown in the `localhost:3000/room` page

Here's a code sandbox: [Link to Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-dream-6ot0d?file=/src/components/MainComponent.js)
Just enter: `https://6ot0d.csb.app/home` on the right side of the browser

Home Component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import Room from './RoomComponent'

function Home(){
    const [joined, setJoined] = useState(false)
    const handleJoin = () => setJoined(true)

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <h3>Welcome, Student</h3>
            <Room name={joined ? "joined" : "not joined"} />
            <Button onClick={handleJoin} variant="contained" color="primary">Join Room</Button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Room Component

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function Room(props){

    if(props.name == "joined"){
        console.log("Accept")
    } else {
        console.log("Wait")

    }

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>Room</div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Room;
```

Main Component

```
function Main(){
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header />
                <Switch>
                <Container maxWidth="sm">
                    <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
                    <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                    <Route path='/room' component={Room} />                
                </Container>
                </Switch>
            {/* <Footer /> */}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Main);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you might be after sockets. This would involve creating a server, which you would send messages/events to. Your home component would send a join message to the server, and the room component (ie: /room page) would listen for messages sent from the server to it to react to anyone joining. One library for using sockets is socket.io

Comment: When you navigate to `/room` you are not rendering `Room` with a prop of `name`. Therefore, `props.name` will always be undefined. What is the purpose of navigating to `/room`?

Comment: @SinanYaman - hi, the purpose is to get all the users that will join, however, I might just want to do it on a basic part. I am still learning react. Thank you

Comment: @NickParsons - hello, what if I want the participants to be in a waiting room first before joining and accept them with the privilege of moderator is this possible? let's say I will not use socket at the moment.